# Is "He should have gone running away" grammatical?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, perfect-aspect

Is the use of the construction *should have gone running away* correct?
Would not a better answer be “should have run away”? A teacher at my school had this question on her students exam and is curious if it is an acceptable answer.

The full sentence from which the above was taken is:

> The cheetah tended to the sick lion and was eaten. He should have gone running away instead of helping the lion.

I'm not sure if the use of “...he should have gone running away...” is grammatically acceptable.

Comment: Please write the full sentence where the phrase was used and tell us what you understand from your own research and what bothers you most. Otherwise, you question will be closed as unclear.

Comment: I think *He should have gone running away...* has a certain poetic beauty to it. @Rathony?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary How about *He should have gone flying away*?

Comment: @Rathony, that's better! :')

Comment: Don't see any problem with that sentence. Your version would give a slightly different meaning. Here the focus is more on the disappearance of the animal. Simply saying he should have run way means the same thing but doesn't emphasize the gone/disappearance part. English as any other language, has many ways to describe the same thing with small subtleties.

Comment: This sounds like a 'go hunting / fishing / shopping / dancing' verbs-in-phase construction and is very awkward (as it is not such) at best. Although 'He should have started running away' is grammatical, it could be argued that this is not exactly the same structure, and grammaticality is not the only thing influencing 'acceptability' in any case. Quirk and Svartvik suggested a 5-point scale of 'acceptability' (but I don't think it was generally accepted!) So these issues often (as here) depend on whose views on 'acceptability' you choose.

Comment: Patrick (3 hours ago): *I've [edited the OP](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/335536/edit) with the question as set out in the student's exam but it hasn't shown up yet. I do apologize for the confusion* So where's the exam question, complete with blank space then?

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 4):

It really seems to me that "running away" is *describing* the way in which he ran. We can add some clarifying punctuation:

> He should have gone, running away, instead of helping the lion.

(Most people prefer commas, I think, although I'd prefer em-dashes. Either seems acceptable here.)

The way it is given, with "should have gone running away", definitely reads a bit awkwardly for me as a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

"gone" in this sense is the past tense of "go" as in ***"to go and do something"***.  It's typically used with recreational activities, particularly exercise, like *"He's gone swimming"* or *"I should have gone running this morning."* or *"She's gone to play frisbee in the park"*.  There's an implication that you **go somewhere else in order to do the activity**.

"should have gone running away" suggests that "running away" is an activity, perhaps recreational, which the subject should have gone somewhere to do, which isn't what is intended.

It would be better to simply write **"He should have run away"** instead.

Comment: @Mari-LouA seems clear enough to me - I have answered my interpretation of the question, at least, which is all that I could ever do for any question.

Comment: The exam question had a blank that had to be filled in. Do you know what that blank space was? Usually blanks in exams are for single words not for clauses. Maybe the exam paper was a multiple choice one. I find the OP question as clear as mud at this point.

Comment: Added for clarification. Please see the trail of comments in [Patrick's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/335541/44619) It's not clear what the original sentence in the exam question was. – Mari-Lou A 11 mins ago

Comment: On closer inspection of all the comments etc, I'm now also confused about what the actual question is.  The OP needs some sort of virtual slap for the chaos of this question.  Ah well, I'll leave my answer here in case it's useful.